# How to create table like another table with additional columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 'Name, Age, Gender' columns in a 'test' table.

I now, want to create another table 'test1' which will have these columns :
'Name, Age, Gender, Occupation'.

How do I do it without creating and then altering? Is there any way to do it in a single line?

I tried adding one column, but I was able to add it at the start only, like:
CREATE TABLE test1 (Occupation VARCHAR(50)) LIKE test;

This would result in 'Occupation, Name, Age, Gender'.

I tried CREATE TABLE test1 LIKE test (Occupation VARCHAR(50)) which gave me an error.

How to add columns at last while creation?

Comment: You can use ```CREATE TABLE table LIKE  table2``` and add columns with ```ALTER table ADD COLUMN```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `CREATE TABLE AS ...` with a select containing the new column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 AS
SELECT Name, Age, Gender, '' AS Occupation
FROM test;
```

The above simply places empty string as the value for the new occupation column.  If you want some other value, then you would need to provide logic for how to populate it.

Comment: That's alright. But, what If I have to add primary key or foreign key with references? Can that be done here without using alter table?

Comment: I might suggest using a formal `CREATE TABLE` statement, then populate the data in a second query.  Nothing wrong with doing this, by the way.

Comment: What if your table has 100s of columns? Are you going to hardcode the names?!

Answer (score 2):

Though you have obligation regarding adding the column at the begining, I am sharing here two approaches with which you can add a column along with the constraint while creating new table from old one.

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
     name varchar(100),
     age int,
     gender char(1)
 );

 INSERT INTO test values('name1',30,'M');

 INSERT INTO test values('name2',50,'F');
```

Create table statement from old table:

```
 CREATE TABLE test1 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             PRIMARY KEY (id))
             SELECT *  FROM test;
```

Select query on old table:

```
 SELECT* FROM test;
```

Output:

| name | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 30 | M |
| name2 | 50 | F |

Slect query on new table:

```
 select * from test1
```

OUtput:

| id | name | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 30 | M |
| 2 | name2 | 50 | F |

Another approach is to create a new table with all the column names from old table with the new column at the end

```
 CREATE TABLE test2 (
     name varchar(100),
     age int,
     gender char(1),
     id int not null auto_increment,
     primary key(id)
 );
```

Then insert the data from old table to new table with a single insert statement:

```
 insert into test2 (name,age,gender) select name, age, gender from test
```

Select query on new table:

```
 select * from test2
```

Output:

| name | age | gender | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 30 | M | 1 |
| name2 | 50 | F | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2300447b92d714724456008dd7bcafbd)*

Comment: What's the difference between omitting the `AS` in your answer when compared with [@TimBiegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231797/2263631)?

Comment: In my answer I added a primary key column while creating the table as it's been asked for in a comment.